# R: Regex in strsplit (finding ", " followed by capital letter)

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

Say I have a vector containing some characters that I want to split based on a regular expression.

To be more precise, I want to split the strings based on a comma, followed by a space, and then by a capital letter (to my understanding, the `regex` command looks like this: `/(, [A-Z])/g` (which works fine when I try it [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/iR8gC4/1))).

When I try to achieve this in `r`, the `regex` doesn't seem to work, for example:

```
x <- c("Non MMF investment funds, Insurance corporations, Assets (Net Acquisition of), Loans, Long-term original maturity (over 1 year or no stated maturity)",
  "Non financial corporations, Financial corporations other than MFIs, insurance corporations, pension funds and non-MMF investment funds, Assets (Net Acquisition of), Loans, Short-term original maturity (up to 1 year)")

strsplit(x, "/(, [A-Z])/g")
[[1]]
[1] "Non MMF investment funds, Insurance corporations, Assets (Net Acquisition of), Loans, Long-term original maturity (over 1 year or no stated maturity)"

[[2]]
[1] "Non financial corporations, Financial corporations other than MFIs, insurance corporations, pension funds and non-MMF investment funds, Assets (Net Acquisition of), Loans, Short-term original maturity (up to 1 year)"
```

It finds no split. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should not use `/.../g`. It is not JS. And I guess you do not want to omit the letter, do you? Try [this](http://ideone.com/YfnJWL).

Comment: Delimiters are not used in R and the `strsplit` function is consuming the characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
strsplit(x, ", (?=[A-Z])", perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/YfnJWL)

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Non MMF investment funds"                                       
[2] "Insurance corporations"                                         
[3] "Assets (Net Acquisition of)"                                    
[4] "Loans"                                                          
[5] "Long-term original maturity (over 1 year or no stated maturity)"

[[2]]
[1] "Non financial corporations"                                                                                
[2] "Financial corporations other than MFIs, insurance corporations, pension funds and non-MMF investment funds"
[3] "Assets (Net Acquisition of)"                                                                               
[4] "Loans"                                                                                                     
[5] "Short-term original maturity (up to 1 year)"
```

The regex - `", (?=[A-Z])"` - contains a look-ahead `(?=[A-Z])` that checks but does not consume the uppercase letter. In R, you need to use `perl=T` with regexps that contain lookarounds.

If the space is optional, or there can be double space between the comma and the uppercase letter, use

```
strsplit(x, ",\\s*(?=[A-Z])", perl=T)
```

And one more variation that will support Unicode letters (with `\\p{Lu}`):

```
strsplit(x, ", (?=\\p{Lu})", perl=T)
```

Comment: @Thomas: I do not think it is a competition. At least I do not think of that as such. We all win here. Unless someone starts downvoting without explanation.

Comment: I meant, you typed faster & better than me, but I was too lazy to write it down